How to build ReactJs with Gradle
I want to build a Micronaut app using Gradle with ReactJs as frontend.
How to build ReactJs with Gradle?

You can use https://github.com/siouan/frontend-gradle-plugin. Example repo that I've been working on: https://github.com/statisticsnorway/kostra-kontrollprogram. See web-frontend and web modules for frontend and backend.
